# Apache open NLP POS incorrect Tagging

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I have used Stanford NLP but due to their more strict licensing terms ( though it is stated as GPL , it can be used only for non-profit projects ) , I am evaluating Apache Open NLP.

I tried a basic sample test and found that the parts of speech was tagged incorrectly in Open NLP .
For eg : words like "load" , "loading" are marked as NN where as they are actually Verbs .

Has anybody faced this issue ? I checked the dictionary of Open NLP and I found few verbs marked as NN

Sample code

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/opennlp/en-pos-maxent.bin");
        System.out.println(" inputStream " + inputStream);

        POSModel posModel = null;
        try {
            posModel = new POSModel(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        POSTaggerME posTaggerME = new POSTaggerME(posModel);

        String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize("Chair damaged during loading:");

        String[] tags = posTaggerME.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);


        IntStream.range(0, tags.length).forEach(i -> System.out.println(" POS " + tags[i]));
```

Comment: How did you test these words? As separate strings? Even Stanford NLP makes mistakes when you pass partial strings.

Comment: I had passed as an array of String as suggested in the documentation

Comment: Could you share your code? Are you using 1.5.x or 1.6?

Comment: I am using 1.6 .  Code is updated in the question

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, Because OpenNLP doesn't guarantee for 100% accuracy.Because It uses a prediction methodology.It predicts the result looking at features.That means pos taggers.It looks relations of pos taggers near the word which should be detected. So all the predictions depend on your training data set. For a good training data set, you need to have 15,000 lines in your training data set. There are no other alternative options.
You are testing your sentence with a pre-trained model which was trained by Apache developers. So there may be mismatch results with your data and data which was used to train the pre-trained model. So I suggest you to train a new model with your data.It causes to increase the prediction probability.

NOTE: Look at documentation for how to train a new model. It explains nicely.